# Comparing rows within Grouping

Tags: postgresql

So I've already written code and gotten a table to the point of:

| Region | Position | Specialty | Charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SF | F | *null* | 10 |
| SF | F | R | 10 |
| SF | F | S | 10 |
| SF | F | T | 11 |
| SF | F | U | 12 |
| SF | F | V | 12 |
| SF | G | *null* | 13 |
| SF | G | R | 13 |
| SF | G | S | 16 |
| SF | G | T | 17 |
| SF | G | U | 18 |
| SF | G | V | 20 |

So here's what the table looks like currently. Every region has available positions, and every position has available specialties, with the top line item always being the *null* specialty, aka the Base Charge for that position.

Essentially the goal of this report is to exclude any of the specialties that have the same charge as the base charge. I'm having trouble doing this so the person who this report is for is okay with an extra column that clearly states if the base rate is the same as that specialty rate. Grouping of the specialties is something they don't want. I tried giving them something with String Aggregates that went had the specialties with the same rates in the cell separated by a comma, however, they don't prefer this.

Is there any functions I can use to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where not exists` to filter out the rows that match the base rate:

```
select *
  from your_table t
 where specialty is null
    or not exists (select 1 
                     from your_table
                    where region = t.region
                      and position = t.position
                      and charge = t.charge
                      and specialty is null)
```

Comment: So this filtered out all specialties, the report only show's entries with null specialties now

Comment: @RushiPatel  It doesn't fail here:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9oeKYnbF2LE5GnMH6t2Yrd/0